# Generating a JSON map containing shell variables named in a list

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, jq

My shell-fu is at a below-beginner level. I have a file that contains some lines that happen to be the names of environment variables.

e.g.

```
ENV_VAR_A
ENV_VAR_B
...
```

What I want to do is use this file to generate a JSON string containing the names and current values of the named variables using jq like this:

```
jq -n --arg arg1 "$ENV_VAR_A" --arg arg2 "$ENV_VAR_B" '{ENV_VAR_A:$arg1,ENV_VAR_B:$arg2}'

# if ENV_VAR_A=one and ENV_VAR_B=two then the preceding command would output 
# {"ENV_VAR_A":"one","ENV_VAR_B":"two"}
```

I'm trying to create the jq command through a shell script and I have no idea what I'm doing :(

Comment: @CharlesDuffy which further demonstrates the difficulty I'm having with this....I know it doesn't have to be exported to the environment, but if it is an environment variable this syntax works (not sure if should be doing something different). I've already been able to run the command to do exactly what I wanted, but now I need to do it dynamically (based on a whitelist)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, but I also want the keys of the generated JSON string to be from the file as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short and sweet (if you have jq 1.5 or higher):

```
 jq -Rn '[inputs | {(.): env[.]}] | add' tmp.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want here is an *indirect reference*. Those can be done with `${!varname}`. As a trivial example limited to exactly two lines:

```
# read arg1_varname and arg2_varname from the first two lines of file.txt
{ read -r arg1_varname; read -r arg2_varname; } <file.txt

# pass the variable named by the contents of arg1_varname as $arg1 in jq
# and the variable named by the contents of arg2_varname as $arg2 in jq
jq -n --arg arg1_name "$arg1_varname" --arg arg1_value "${!arg1_varname}" \
      --arg arg2_name "$arg2_varname" --arg arg2_value "${!arg2_varname}" \
  '{($arg1_name):$arg1_value, ($arg2_name):$arg2_value}'
```

To support an arbitrary number of key/value pairs, consider instead something like:

```
# Transform into NUL-separate key=value pairs (same format as /proc/*/environ)
while IFS= read -r name; do                             # for each variable named in file.txt
  printf '%s=%s\0' "$name" "${!name}"                   # print its name and value, and a NUL
done \
  <file.txt \
  | jq -Rs 'split("\u0000")                             # split on those NULs
            | [.[] | select(.)                          # ignore any empty strings
               | capture("^(?<name>[^=]+)=(?<val>.*)$") # break into k/v pairs
               | {(.name): .val}]                       # make each a JSON map
            | add                                       # combine those maps
  '
```

Comment: Awesome! How could I go about using arg1_varname to replace the ENV_VAR_A in the JSON string generate by jq? And for final massive props is there anyway I could do this entire command simply from the list itself  WITHOUT knowing the number of arguments (just reading the lines from the file)?

Answer (score 2):

`jq` can look up the values from the environment itself.

```
$ export A=1
$ export B=2
$ cat tmp.txt
A
B
$ jq -Rn '[inputs] | map({key: ., value: $ENV[.]}) | from_entries' tmp.txt
{
  "A": "1",
  "B": "2"
}
```

A few notes on how this works:

1. `-R` reads raw text, rather than trying to parse the input as JSON
2. `-n` prevents `jq` from reading input itself.
3. `inputs` reads all the input explicitly, allowing an array of names to be built.
4. `map` creates an array of objects with `key` and `value` as the keys; `.` is the current array input (a variable name), and `$ENV[.]` is the value of the environment variable whose name is the current array input.
5. `from_entries` finally coalesces all those `{"key": ..., "value": ...}` objects into a single object.

Comment: I have no words, amazing.

Comment: ...BUT, I have a further requirement, I am trying to run this in a docker container, `FROM nginx:stable` , I have installed jq and am running `CMD echo $( jq -Rn '[inputs] | map({key: ., value: $ENV[.]}) | from_entries' ./config/env );` but I am getting `jq: error: ENV/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
[inputs] | map({key: ., value: $ENV[.]}) | from_entries `....any ideas?

Comment: You need the newest (1.6, at the time of this writing) version of `jq` for `$ENV`.

Comment: If you have `jq` 1.5, you can use `env[.]` in place of `$ENV[.]`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I just took a look at my Docker build and it's installing 1.5 with `apt-get install jq` so env[.] will work!

Comment: You could always grab the latest version directly from https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/, as the binary is statically linked and useable pretty much as-is, but good to know you can adapt the version supplied by your base image.

Comment: Also, you don't need the `echo`: `CMD jq -Rn ... ` will suffice.

Comment: Also see [@peak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59782849/1126841) for a more streamlined version.

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the following script in bash:

```
# array of arguments to pass to jq
jqarg=()
# the script to pass to jq
jqscript=""
# just a number for the arg$num for indexing
# suggestion: just index using variable names...
num=1

# for each variable name from the input
while IFS= read -r varname; do

   # just an assertion - check if the variable is not empty
   # the syntax ${!var} is indirect reference
   # you could do more here, ex. see if such variable exists
   # or if $varname is a valid variable name
   if [[ -z "${!varname}" ]]; then
        echo "ERROR: variable $varname has empty value!" >&2
        exit 50
   fi

   # add the arguments to jqarg array
   jqarg+=(--arg "arg$num" "${!varname}")
   # update jqscript
   # if jqscript is not empty, add a comma on the end
   if [[ -n "$jqscript" ]]; then
      jqscript+=","
   fi
   # add the ENV_VAR_A:$arg<number>
   jqscript+="$varname:\$arg$num"
   # update number - one up!
   num=$((num + 1))

# the syntax of while read loop is that input file is on the end
done < input_file_with_variable_names.txt

# finally execute jq
# note the `{` and `}` in `{$jqscript}` are concious
jq -n "${jqarg[@]}" "{$jqscript}"
```

Just something that hopefully will give you a easier start with your journey in bash.

I guess *I* would do something unreadable with `xargs` like:

```
< input_file_with_variable_names.txt xargs -d$'\n' -n1 bash -c '
   printf %s\\0%s\\0%s\\0 --arg "$1" "${!1}"
' -- |
xargs -0 sh -c 'jq -n "$@" "$0"' "{$(
     sed 's/\(.*\)/\1: $\1 /' input_file_with_variable_names.txt | 
     paste -sd,
)}"
```

Comment: Heh. I'm working on something that's maybe a *little* more elegant, but this is actually how I've solved this problem in practice myself in the past. :)

Comment: You and @CharlesDuffy are both amazingly helpful, thanks so much to both of you.