# sed unterminated `s' command with jq json string

Tags: json, shell, sed, jq, edit

Piggybacking off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59778578/generating-a-json-map-containing-shell-variables-named-in-a-list/59779106?noredirect=1#comment105717845_59779106) I have a command (running in a Docker container) where I am trying to sed to replace an expression with a JSON string generated by jq.

Tiny backstory:

I have a whitelist of env vars in a file `tmp.txt`:

```
ENV_VAR_A
ENV_VAR_B
ENV_VAR_C
```

I use jq using the answer in the previous thread to generate a JSON string like this:

```
jq -Rn '[inputs | {(.): env[.]}] | add' ./tmp.txt
# GENERATES { "ENV_VAR_A": "a val", "ENV_VAR_B": "a val", "ENV_VAR_C": "a val"}
```

Amazing! Now I am trying to use sed (as a Docker `CMD`) to do replace something:

```
# CMD sed -i 's@{{SOME_PATTERN}}@'$( jq -Rn '[inputs | {(.): env[.]}] | add' ./etc/nginx/conf.d/env)'@' ./somefile
```

But I am getting:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unterminated `s' command
```

So something went wrong the substitution - but I am not nearly knowledgeable enough in shell to figure out how to fix it, I feel like I have to move some quotes/delimiters around, or maybe pipe my jq to something to "clean up" the json string before I substitute, but I'm not sure what.

Looking for some sed-fu, can anyone help?

Comment: Rather than struggling with getting sed to work with jq, why not do everything using just jq?  Maybe it would help if you gave some illustration of what `somefile` might look like.

Comment: @peak it’s an HTML file, I’m replacing a placeholder with a JSON string.

Comment: If your jq supports the --rawfile command-line option, then it would be easy to use jq to perform both tasks.

Comment: @peak what would that look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky since replacement string has many lines. You can try this `sed` with a process substitution:

```
sed -i -e '/{{SOME_PATTERN}}/r '<( jq -Rn '[inputs | {(.): env[.]}] | add' /etc/nginx/conf.d/env) -e '//d' somefile
```

Make sure you're using `bash`.

With a bit modified `jq` command that produces single line output, you can just do:

```
sed -i 's/{{SOME_PATTERN}}/'"$(jq -nRc '[inputs | {(.): env[.]}] | add' /etc/nginx/conf.d/env)"'/' somefile
```

Comment: I didn't know replacement string had many lines, I thought it was "flat" - can I just use `jq` to minify the JSON output to make things easier on sed?

Comment: Same command, I was trying to pipe the output of the jq command to ` | jq -c` but I think I'm missing something

Comment: ok even that command i.e. `jq -nRc '[inputs | {(.): env[.]}] | add' tmp.txt` will work fine with my suggested `sed` command.Try it and let me know.

Comment: `-nRc` works! I had no intention of my replacement string having many lines, now I can see why sed was choking. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

@Adam asked:

> what would that look like?

If your jq has the --rawfile option, there should be no need to juggle jq and sed:

```
< somefile jq -R --rawfile text tmp.txt '
  ($text
   | split("\n")
   | map(select(length>0)
   | {(.): env[.]}) | add) as $json
  | sub("{{SOME_PATTERN}}"; $json|tostring)'
```